# Stroring document.getElementById() in a const variable

Tags: javascript

Why does the code below run fine? const is short for constant and its value should never changed

```js
const myHeading = document.getElementById("myHeading") ;
myHeading.addEventListener("click", () => {
  myHeading.style.color("red") ;
}) ;
```

Comment: It means you can't reassign another value to myHeading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable declared with `const` can never be *reassigned* - if you see

```
const someVarName = <something>
```

what that prohibits is a later statement with `someVarName` on the left-hand side:

```
someVarName = <something else> // TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

It does not prohibit mutation, such as

```
someVarName.foo = 'foo';
```

You're not reassigning `myHeading` to something else, so there's no problem.